# Generating variables

Tags: php, html, variables, input

I am building a site-dictionary where you can search for more than one word at a time. I have a button to add inputs, one for each term. Now, i use those inputs and through a dictionary site (legally) i obtain their definitions and apply my own css style to them. So, when you type your word in input 1 (let's call it the like that) you get its definition in a div next to the input. So i have one variable to request the word, four others for the fetching and styling, an one last "echo" for the output. Here is the code:

```
enter code <?php
    $data = preg_replace('/(search?[\d\w]+)/','http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/\1', $data);
    $word = $_REQUEST['word'];
    $word2 = $_REQUEST['word2'];

    $url = "http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val={$word}";
    $url2 = "http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val={$word2}";

    $css = <<<EOT

    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
    EOT;

$data = file_get_contents($url);
$data2 = file_get_contents($url2);
$data = str_replace('<head>', $css.'</head>', $data);
$data2 = str_replace('<head>', $css.'</head>', $data2);
$data = str_replace('<span class="f"><b>.</b></span>', '', $data);
$data2 = str_replace('<span class="f"><b>.</b></span>', '', $data2);
      echo '<div id="result1"
      style="">
     '.$data.' 
     </div>';

      echo '<div id="result1"
      style="">
     '.$data2.' 
     </div>';

        ?>
```

Issue: how can i automatically generate this varibles (actually, the process itself) for every new input added?

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst in a perfect world you should make that comment an answer, and that answer should be accepted.

Comment: @Asad Well I see it this way, that comment is all the OP needs to  solve their problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are what you're looking for. Instead of creating a new variable $data{INDEX} you can create one variable that can hold a range of variables.

For example, if you want to 'push' an array with data you can do this.

```
$myData = array();

// appends the contents to the array
$myData[] = file_get_contents($url);
$myData[] = file_get_contents($url2);
```

Arrays allow for more versatility and efficiency.

You can find the documentation **[here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)**.

A full implementation would look something like this.

```
// create an array of requests that we want
// to load in the url.
$words = array('word', 'word2');

// we'll use this later on for loading the files.
$baseUrl = 'http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=';

// string to replace in the head.
$cssReplace = '<style type="text/css"></style></head>';

// string to remove in the document.
$spanRemove = '<span class="f"><b>.</b></span>';

// use for printing out the result ID.
$resultIndex = 0;

// loop through the words we defined above
// load the respective file, and print it out.
foreach($words as $word) {
    // check if the request with
    // the given word exists. If not,
    // continue to the next word
    if(!isset($_REQUEST[$word]))
        continue;

    // load the contents of the base url and requested word.
    $contents = file_get_contents($baseUrl . $_REQUEST[$word]);

    // replace the data defined above.
    $contents = str_replace('</head>', $cssReplace, $contents);
    $contents = str_replace($spanRemove, '', $contents);

    // print out the result with the result index.
    // ++$resultIndex simply returns the value of 
    // $resultIndex after adding one to it.
    echo '<div id="result', (++$resultIndex) ,'">', $contents ,'</div>';
}
```

Comment: sorry, but when you wrote: "loop through the words we defined above" are these "$myData[] = file_get_contents($url);
$myData[] = file_get_contents($url2);" And also, how can i add an input, and automatically name it word3, word4,     Thanks anyway!

Comment: The first example isn't related to the second example. To add word3 and word4 you can just add them to the words array. `array('word', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4', etc);`

Comment: Understood, yet only one of the "words" is giving an ouput, the rest don't. Shouldn't all the inputs be named "word"? Isn't it like that in the loop?

Comment: Here is how i add inputs: $(function(){
            $('#addinput').click(function(){
                $('#inputs').append('<input class="search" type="search" results/>');
            });
        });